# Изменение кода метода в отдельных экземплярах класса

Tags: java, ооп, классы, полиморфизм

Допустим, у нас есть класс `Class`, в котором есть метод `public void SendMessage { System.out.println("Blah!"); }`. Мы создаем объекты A и B. Допустим, нужно, чтобы объект B использовал какую-то другую реализацию метода `SendMessage`. Возможно ли в Java сделать это, не создавая для `B` отдельный класс, наследующий от `Class`?

Comment: Такой вариант, как передавать в метод аргумент со строкой, которую надо вывести не подходит?

Comment: Ваш вопрос чисто теоретический или у вас есть практическая задача, которую вы хотели бы так решить? Если задача практическая, лучше приведите исходную задачу. Вероятно, её можно решить по-другому.

Comment: Ещё почитайте [здесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/183331)

Comment: @TagirValeev пишу шахматный движок, в котором есть два типа позиции: обдумываемая и реальная (на доске). Поскольку реальная позиция только одна, не хотелось бы ради одного экземпляра создавать отдельный класс.

Comment: Забыл сказать, реальную позицию нужно после каждого хода записывать в историю, поэтому хотелось бы добавить запись в историю в функцию, делающую ход.

Comment: @velikiyv4, на эту тему не парьтесь. Ничего плохого, если у вас отдельный класс только для одного объекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто переопределяйте метод не в наследнике, а непосредственно при создании экземпляра класса:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SomeClass A = new SomeClass();

        SomeClass B = new SomeClass(){
            @Override
            public void sendMessage() {
                System.out.print("Babah!!");
            }
        };

        A.sendMessage();
        B.sendMessage();
    }
}

public class SomeClass {

    public void sendMessage (){
        System.out.println("Blah!");
    }
}
```

Результат работы программы:

> Blah!
>   Babah!!

Comment: Таки вы создаёте отдельный класс в данном случае, просто он анонимный. `B.getClass().equals(A.getClass())` вернёт `false`. И количество загруженных классов в приложении будет больше. Ну, может, вопрошающего это решение устроит, всё равно более честного варианта «не создавая класс» не бывает.

Comment: @TagirValeev Да, так и есть. Это единственное адекватное решение, которое мне пришло в голову. Мне трудно представить, где на практике может понадобиться "чистое" решение вопроса. Скорее всего автор не до конца понимает саму концепцию ООП и пытается придумать "велосипед".

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте методу SendMessage переопределение.

Если такой вариант вам не подходит, ознакомьтесь с этим:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

Так же можете ознакомиться с этой статьей:

http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/05/21/delegates.html?page=2

Comment: Наверное не перегрузка (одно имя метода, с разной сигнатурой аргументов), а переопределение (изменение выполняемых действий в потомках/экземплярах)

Comment: @pavlofff наверно перегрузки), public void sendMessage(int a){sout("Ah!");}

Comment: @МихаилКетов Абсолютно точно - переопределение (override), а не перегрузка (overload). [Подробный ликбез по вопросу](http://java-course.ru/begin/override-overload/).